# Mysql Join issue with self defined table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query. I am trying to join a table with a defined table. But the problem is when we are trying Left join it effects same like inner join.

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,
 (CASE WHEN A.preday != '' THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END) AS PreStat 
 FROM (
   SELECT '2016-05-04' AS preday 
   UNION 
   SELECT '2016-05-03' 
   UNION 
   SELECT '2016-05-02'
 ) AS A 
 LEFT JOIN `student_attendence` AS B ON B.date = A.preday 
 WHERE student_id='1' ;
```

For example in my right table doesn't contain a date field with value '2016-05-02' , But when we are trying left join it should come with NULL values ..but it won't come.

my right join table structure is
[image]

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: What does "self defined" mean here? Also, please, whenever possible post the **text** of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of a picture.

Comment: alter the `where student_ID = '1'` to `as student_ID = '1'` so it's part of the join instead of the where.  This way the limit is applied before the join and the null records created by the join remain.

Comment: @tadman that means left table data is dynamicaly defined according to the circumstances..

Comment: What circumstances? If the circumstances aren't relevant then this is something that doesn't need to be mentioned. It's not clear what sort of results you're trying to get here, so a sample bit of the desired output would help clarify.

Comment: @tadman that is in my query part SELECT '2016-05-04' AS preday 
UNION 
SELECT '2016-05-03' 
UNION 
SELECT '2016-05-02' the dates given inside this are from inputs given by user and it would change dynamically,not a static value.that's i mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this for a second. Student_ID only exists on student_Attendence table (for these 2 tables anway).  A student may not have a record for that given day (must be the case if you're not getting 02 in the results; at least for student 1)  If you want all days from your derived union table; then you need to filter students_ID before the join occurs so the unmatched day for student 1 record is preserved from the left join

```
SELECT A.*,B.*, (CASE WHEN A.preday != '' THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END) AS PreStat 
FROM (SELECT '2016-05-04' AS preday 
      UNION SELECT '2016-05-03' 
      UNION SELECT '2016-05-02') AS A 
LEFT JOIN `student_attendence` AS B 
  ON B.date = A.preday 
  and student_id='1' ;
```

Student_Attendance for Student_ID 1 would be...

```
ID Date
1  2016-05-05
1  2016-05-04
1  2016-05-03
1  2016-05-01
```

So the left join would result in ...

```
Preday            ID Date                   
2016-05-04         1  2016-05-04
2016-05-03         1  2016-05-03
2016-05-02
```

and when you apply the where clause ... since 2016-05-02 has no entry for Student 1, it gets eliminated..

```
Preday            ID Date                   
2016-05-04         1  2016-05-04
2016-05-03         1  2016-05-03
```

But if you move the where clause to the join... you get this as the filter is applied before the join, thus retaining the 02 date.

```
Preday            ID Date                   
2016-05-04         1  2016-05-04
2016-05-03         1  2016-05-03
2016-05-02
```

Comment: Anytime you use an outer join.  The where clause limits can only be on the table in which all records are returned; if you want to preserve all records, otherwise you end up getting an INNER Join result as you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

the reason because of the logical query processing of the query as the first clause to be executed is the from clause then where > grouping > having > select > order by

so when you execute your own query the first clause to be executed is the from which returned '2016-05-02' with null as expected with the left join
but the where clause after that filters the result set and remove it because the null is unknown (it isn't a value, it stands for missing value)

so you can do something like replacing the where clause with and operator.